# Converting string to date in the most concise way in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I loaded a `DataFrame` from a csv file and one column contains a date/time string, in order to convert it to an actual date object I am currently doing this:

```py
mydata["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(mydata["date_time"], errors='raise')
```

However I feel like there may be a more concise way of doing this but can't find it.

Am I doing things right or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will convert to date time with `read_csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', parse_dates=['date_time'])
```